# how to use DOM element in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dom

I want to do getElementById to give css effect and click to slide function.
how do I use DOM in react? Thank you in advance.

```js
    function Auth() {
    //this part needs to be fixed
    const signUpButton = document.getElementById('signUp');
    const signInButton = document.getElementById('signIn');
    const container = document.getElementById('body');
    
    signUpButton.addEventListener('click', () =>
    container.classList.add('right-panel-active'));

    signInButton.addEventListener('click', () =>
    container.classList.remove('right-panel-active'));
```

Here are the classnames that might help you understand my code better.

```js
    return (
        
        <div className ="auth">
            <div className="body" id="body">
                <SignUp className="test" />
                <SignIn className="test" />
                <div className="slide__body">
                    <div className="slides">
                        <div className="slide SignUp__left">
                        <p>Already have an account?</p>
                            <button className="slide__btn" id='signUp'  > Sign In </button>
                        </div>
                        <div className="slide SignIn__right">
                            <p>Not a Member?</p>
                            <button className="slide__btn" id='signIn'  > Sign Up </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: In react you should use refs for that, you may want to look at this https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

Comment: Yes, you should use refs when you need to access the DOM directly in React. And there are quite a few valid use-cases for that. But you should always think twice and see if there's a more "React-like" way to do what you want. Here you appear to just want to add event listeners, which you should do in React just by adding `onclick` (etc) attributes to your JSX output. (And rather than adding classes imperatively, those event handlers should toggle some state, and your rendered output should add the relevant class or not depending on that state.)

Comment: ... or in other words , you need to fire the function onload : `window.onload= Auth;` else your addEventListeners will never be added ...

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid direct modification of the dom in React. React assumes that it is the only piece of code modifying the dom, and so it won't know about any changes you make. This opens up the possibility of bugs where react changes something on the dom that you don't expect, or doesn't change something you do expect. A simple piece of code like yours won't have these bugs, but best to learn the react way now so you don't run into these issues with more complicated code.

The react way to do this is to pass onClick props to the elements that need it, and to have a state variable which controls the class names. For example:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Auth() {
  const [showPanel, setShowPanel] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="auth">
      <div className={showPanel ? "body right-panel-active" : "body"}>
        <SignUp className="test" />
        <SignIn className="test" />
        <div className="slide__body">
          <div className="slides">
            <div className="slide SignUp__left">
              <p>Already have an account?</p>
              <button
                className="slide__btn"
                onClick={() => setShowPanel(false)}
              >
                Sign In
              </button>
            </div>
            <div className="slide SignIn__right">
              <p>Not a Member?</p>
              <button 
                className="slide__btn" 
                onClick={() => setShowPanel(true)}
              >
                Sign Up
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the propose to use React is that fact you should interact in the component state.

I suggest you use State in your component and add some according to some interaction

```
 function App() {
  const [mode, setMode] = React.useState();

  const handleMode = (mode) => {
    setMode(mode);
  };

  const containerClasses =
    mode === "signUp" ? "body right-panel-active" : "body";

  return (
    <div className="auth">
      <div className={containerClasses} id="body">
        <SignUp className="test" />
        <SignIn className="test" />
        <div className="slide__body">
          <div className="slides">
            <div className="slide SignUp__left">
              <p>Already have an account?</p>
              <button
                className="slide__btn"
                id="signUp"
                onClick={() => handleMode("signIn")}
              >
                {" "}
                Sign In{" "}
              </button>
            </div>
            <div className="slide SignIn__right">
              <p>Not a Member?</p>
              <button
                className="slide__btn"
                id="signIn"
                onClick={() => handleMode("signUp")}
              >
                {" "}
                Sign Up{" "}
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```